# Permute strings not working as expected

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function which permutes all possible combination of one word and the program create duplicates of permute strings and I can not figure out why.

This is my working code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char arr[5000] = {0};
void swap (char *x, char *y);
void permute(char *ptr, size_t i, size_t n);

int main(void){
    char str[80] = "MICHI";
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    permute(str, 0, len );
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    printf("END\n");
}

void swap (char *x, char *y){
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *ptr, size_t i, size_t n){
    size_t j;
    if (i == n){
        strcat (arr, ptr);
        strcat (arr, "\n");
    }else{
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {

            swap( (ptr + i), (ptr + j) );
            permute(ptr, i+1, n);
            swap( (ptr + i), (ptr + j) );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Output:

```
ABC
AB
ACB
AC
A
A
BAC
BA
BCA
BC
B
B
CBA
CB
CAB
CA
C
C







END
```

Expected Outputs should be:

```
ABC
AB
ACB
AC
A
BAC
BA
BCA
BC
B
CBA
CB
CAB
CA
c
```

The program creates a lot of duplicates and it creates also lots of New Lines two.

Noticed that if the INPUT is for example `MICHI`, I get duplicates like this:

```
IMCHI
IMCH
IMCIH
IMCI
```

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: If your input contains duplicate characters, like the two `I` in MICHI, then there should be duplicate permutations. When you permute, the two `I`s are considered different entities. Or do you just want the combinations (that is, the unique permutations)?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Sorry for late respons, No I do not need unique permutations, because like you said it could be different entities and you right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including the string terminator `\0` in your permutation.

The internal state of `line` is:

```
ABC\0
AB\0C
ACB\0
AC\0B
A\0CB
A\0BC
BAC\0
BA\0C
BCA\0
BC\0A
B\0AC
B\0CA
CBA\0
CB\0A
CAB\0
CA\0B
C\0AB
C\0BA
\0ABC
\0ACB
\0BAC
\0BCA
\0CAB
\0CBA
```

`printf` only prints up to the ending `0`.

One way to fix it is to reduce the loop limit by one and exclude the `\0` from the permutation. You then have to add a second loop that creates a substring that excludes the `i`th character and call `permute` for that substring.

Another way is to stop permuting once a branch is beyond the `\0`.

**EDIT:**

Here is an implementation of the second suggestion that "stops permuting" by suppressing output if a permutation is identical with the previous one. It even seems to produce the order you specified in the example:

```
void permute(char *ptr, size_t i, size_t n){
    size_t j;
    static char prev[80] = "";
    if (i == n){
        if (strcmp(prev, ptr)) {
            strcat (arr, ptr);
            strcat (arr, "\n");
            strcpy(prev, ptr);
        }
    }else{
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {

            swap( (ptr + i), (ptr + j) );
            permute(ptr, i+1, n);
            swap( (ptr + i), (ptr + j) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need somehow the expected Output from my Question.

Comment: @Michi This one seems to work. Note that it will print duplicates if any character occurs more than once.

Comment: This is what I needed. Now I see where the Problem was. +1. Your code does not print `M` (if the input is `MICHI`) but I fix it.

Comment: @Michi Excellent! Would you like to share the fix/working code? Either post it as an answer of your own or edit my answer (your choice!).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your code is fine. I was testing in the wrong file your function. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop in the function permute includes the string's NUL byte. You should just change `j <= n` to `j < n`.
Like this:

```
void permute(char *ptr, size_t i, size_t n){
    size_t j;
    if (i == n){
        strcat (arr, ptr);
        strcat (arr, "\n");
    }else{
        for (j = i; j < n; j++)
        {

            swap( (ptr + i), (ptr + j) );
            permute(ptr, i+1, n);
            swap( (ptr + i), (ptr + j) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good start. That would print all permutations of length `n`. What about the permutations of the shorter substrings?

Comment: Your code changes my desired Output. [This is what I get](https://pastebin.com/raw/ywcTLSmV). Please check my expected Output from my Question.

Comment: Please run your code before posting. This does not work.

Comment: @klutt I did run, and it worked in my PC (but not for the desired output)

Comment: I ran it and only got strings of length 3. https://pastebin.com/NYFVEBkm

Comment: @klutt, permutation uses all the members of the set. The op specified that he wanted variable length permutation after I had written my answer.